# Rails Slow Postgres Query with Order using Index

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am doing a query on my database of a few million items that gets really slow when I add in an order. Here is the code I am calling:

```
Post.where(source_id: source_ids_array).page(1).per(100).order("position asc, external_created_at desc")
```

(I am using Kaminari to do pagination)

Which gives me the following sql:

```
Post Load (36537.8ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."source_id" IN (17805, 18768, 20717, 17803, 17804, 18329, 20705, 19075, 19110, 19082, 18328)  ORDER BY position asc, external_created_at desc LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

However, when I modify the query to just be:

```
Post.where(source_id: source_ids_array).page(1).per(100).order("position asc")
```

I get the following sql:

```
Post Load (279.6ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."source_id" IN (17805, 18768, 20717, 17803, 17804, 18329, 20705, 19075, 19110, 19082, 18328)  ORDER BY position asc LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

Which is insanely faster.

My indexes in my schema.db look like this:

```
add_index "posts", ["external_created_at"], name: "index_posts_on_external_created_at", using: :btree
add_index "posts", ["position", "external_created_at"], name: "index_posts_on_position_and_external_created_at", using: :btree
add_index "posts", ["position"], name: "index_posts_on_position", using: :btree
```

How can I go about speeding up this query?

Edit: here is my EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
Limit  (cost=633132.80..633133.05 rows=100 width=891) (actual time=31927.725..31927.751 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=633132.80..635226.42 rows=837446 width=891) (actual time=31927.720..31927.729 rows=100 loops=1)
        Sort Key: "position", external_created_at
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 78kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on posts  (cost=19878.94..601126.22 rows=837446 width=891) (actual time=487.399..30855.211 rows=858629 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (source_id = ANY ('{17805,18768,20717,17803,17804,18329,20705,19075,19110,19082,18328}'::integer[]))
              Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1050547
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_posts_on_source_id  (cost=0.00..19669.58 rows=837446 width=0) (actual time=485.025..485.025 rows=927175 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_id = ANY ('{17805,18768,20717,17803,17804,18329,20705,19075,19110,19082,18328}'::integer[]))
Total runtime: 31927.998 ms
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for each of the queries (particularly the super-slow one). To do that, open up `psql` or `rails db`, and run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE <rest of SQL goes here>`. Alternatively, I would suggest trying `.order("position asc, external_created_at asc")` (with the orderings in the same direction) and see if that produces a speedier result or not (I *suspect* your compound index is not used due to the mismatched sort directions).

Comment: @RobertNubel You can use `Post.where(source_id: source_ids_array).page(1).per(100).order("position asc, external_created_at desc").explain` in the rails console instead. Much simpler than copypasting into psql

Comment: @max it seems that calling `.explain` only results in a `EXPLAIN SELECT` instead of an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT`

Comment: @goddamnyouryan, your correct there. ActiveRecord seems to have only `EXPLAIN` since its polyglot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although its not very well documented can specify the sort order when creating an index:

```
add_index :posts, [:external_created_at, :position], 
    order: { position: :asc, external_created_at: :desc }
```

If we then run `rake db:structure:dump` we can see that it creates the following SQL:

```
CREATE INDEX "index_posts_on_external_created_at_and_position" 
 ON "posts" ("external_created_at" DESC, "position" ASC);
```

Note that we don't need to specify `using: :btree` since Postgres defaults to using B-tree or the `name:`.

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-ordering.html

Comment: I hope this was helpful. I'm typing on an ancient iMac where inserting a meaningful amount of records would take forever so I was not able to verify that the index is used. I would recommend you mirror the database with pgbackups and test out how to tweak the index and query with `.explain`.

Comment: I tried adding this and it seems to have sped it up a bit, but it's still pretty slow. I edited my question to add the EXPLAIN ANALYZE.

Comment: Ok, I'm at a loss on how to further optimise it. You'll have to wait for the Postgres wizards to show up with their pointy hats.

Comment: It looks like just reversing the order of your index call: `add_index :posts, [:position, :external_created_at], order: { position: :asc, external_created_at: :desc }` has about tripled the query speed! So simple! Of course, this isn't 2 orders of magnitude better, but it's a good start!